# Is there any extension of VScode that find node_modules

Tags: visual-studio-code

If i type `require('...` to find module installed, is there any extension that find the module(snippet) on VScode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is [npm Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.npm-intellisense) extension.